# cakephp + cache query + after refresh lost all data except cachedata

Tags: cakephp, caching

in my controller i cache some paginatedata. after refresh (f5) i get only the data from the cachequeryfile but i lost ALL other data in my view.
why?

cachingmethod: file
cakeversion: 1.2.5
codeexample:

```
$url="home_page_1";
if(!Cache::read($url)){
    $data = $this->paginate('Article');
    Cache::write($url, $data);
}
$data = Cache::read($url);
```

**thanks** hansi meier

Comment: Can you please elaborate, explaining the type of caching used and providing some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(($data = Cache::read($url)) === false){
    $data = $this->paginate('Article');
    Cache::write($url, $data);
}
```